# Client & Server Not Connecting over Local Network

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

Im trying to connect my server application and client application, one is on my computer(host) the other on my guests computer (client) When testing my application out on my computer everything is connecting fine and sending messages etc. but when I launch the JAR file for my guests computer it will not connect it will just close the streams... is there something crucial I'm missing here in context of wifi config etc? this is my first Socket application so I'm clearly not an expert at this stuff but if you could kindly point me in the right direction or point out the problem that would be great thanks.

HOST:

```
    public class EchoClient {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String serverIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            System.out.println(serverIP);

            EchoRun er = new EchoRun(serverIP);
            er.startRunning();

        }

    }
    public class Echo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        private ObjectInputStream input;
        private Socket socket;
        private JTextField userText;
        private JTextArea chatWindow;
        private ServerSocket server;
        private ServerSocket server2;
        private Socket connection;
        private Socket connection2;

        public Echo() {
            super(" Echo Server");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(500, 500);
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            userText = new JTextField();

            userText.setEditable(false);
            chatWindow = new JTextArea();
            userText.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
                    userText.setText(" ");
                }
            });
            add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
            add(chatWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    // let user tyope in the jtextarea

        public void startRunning() {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(2014, 100);

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // will start seperate thread for downloading voice file
                        Thread dow = new Thread(new downloadVoiceFile());
                        dow.start();




                          Thread fileListener = new Thread(new fileListener());
                          fileListener.start();

                        waitForConnection();
                        setUpStreams();
                        whileChatting();

                    } catch (EOFException eofExcption) {
                        showMessage("\n Server Offline");
                    } finally {
                        close();
                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {

            showMessage("\nWaiting For Clients");
            connection = server.accept();
            showMessage(" Now Connected To " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());

        }

        private void setUpStreams() throws IOException {

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            showMessage("\n Streams Established");

        }

        private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
            String message = "\nYou Are Now Connected";
            sendMessage(message);

            ableToType(true);

            do {
                try {

                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    showMessage("\n" + message);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                    showMessage("\n Unknown Error ");
                }

            } while (!message.equals("CLIENT END"));
        }

        private void close() {
            showMessage("\n Closing Connections");
            ableToType(false);
            try {
                output.close();
                input.close();
                connection.close();

            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void sendMessage(String message) {
            try {
                output.writeObject("Server -" + message);
                output.flush();
                showMessage("\n SERVER -" + message);

            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                chatWindow.append("Cannot Send That Message try AGain");
            }

        }

        private void showMessage(final String text) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    chatWindow.append(text);

                }

            }
            );

        }

        public void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    userText.setEditable(tof);
                }

            }
            );
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            Echo echo = new Echo();
            echo.startRunning();

        }

        public void downloadVoiceFile() throws IOException {

            System.out.println("hello from download");
            Thread dow = new Thread(new downloadVoiceFile());
            dow.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }




CLIENT: 


public class EchoRun extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener, Runnable {

    /*
    Audio Vars

     */
    String voiceOutput = "output.wav";
    TargetDataLine line;
    double duration, seconds;
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    /*
    Send File VARS

     */

    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
    private File soundFile;
    private AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private SourceDataLine sourceLine;
/*
    App VARS main
    */
    private JButton file, mic;
    String errStr;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private Socket socket;
    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection;
    private Socket connection2;
    private Socket connection3;

    private String message = "";
    private String serverIP;
    Thread thread;
    JToolBar toolbar;

    public EchoRun(String host) {
        super(" Echo Client");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLookAndFeel();
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        mic = new JButton("Microphone");
        mic.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        mic.setForeground(Color.blue);
        userText.addKeyListener(this);

        file = new JButton("Send File");
        file.addActionListener(this);
        file.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        file.setForeground(Color.blue);
        toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.add(mic);
        toolbar.addSeparator();
        toolbar.add(file);
        toolbar.addSeparator();
        serverIP = host;
        userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(EchoClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                userText.setText(" ");
            }
        });

        add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
        add(chatWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add("North", toolbar);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
                UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }
    }

    public void startRunning() throws IOException {
        try {
            connectToServer();
            setUpStreams();
            whileChatting();
        } catch (EOFException eofException) {
            showMessage("Client Terminated Connection");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeAll();
        }

    }

    /*
    Connect to server
     */
    private void connectToServer() throws IOException {
        // connect to text to text
        showMessage("\nAttempting To Connect To Server For Main Chat");
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 2014);
        showMessage("\nconnected to:" + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());

    }

    private void setUpStreams() throws IOException {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\nStreams Established");
    }

    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
        ableToType(true);
        do {
            try {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                showMessage("\n ERROR SENDING OBJECT");

            }
        } while (!message.equals("SERVER - END"));

    }

    private void closeAll() throws IOException {
        showMessage("\n closing...");
        ableToType(false);
        try {
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        try {
            output.writeObject("\nCLIENT - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\n Client - " + message);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            chatWindow.append("\n ERROR Sending Message");
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void showMessage(final String m) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                chatWindow.append(m);
            }
        });

    }

    private void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
        });

    }

    /*
    Handling the microphone
     */
    public void stop() {
        thread = null;
    }

    public void shutDown(String message) {
        if ((errStr = message) != null && thread != null) {
            thread = null;
            System.err.println(errStr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'q') {

            System.out.println("Started Recording");
            start();

        }
    }

    public void start() {
        errStr = null;
        thread = new Thread((Runnable) this);
        thread.setName("Capture");
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (e.getKeyChar() == 'q') {
            System.out.println("Stopped Recording");
            stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == file) {
            try {
                chooseFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    Choose file method
     */
    public void chooseFile() throws IOException {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setDialogTitle("Send File");
        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        int dialog = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (dialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File inputFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
            inputFile.getName();
            inputFile.getAbsoluteFile();
            String nameOf = inputFile.getName();
            System.out.println(" File: " + inputFile);

            sendFile(inputFile);

        }

    }

    public void sendFile(File inputFile) throws IOException {

        connection3 = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 1991);
        System.out.println("File Being Sent");
        OutputStream output2 = new ObjectOutputStream(connection3.getOutputStream());
        output2.flush();
        InputStream input2 = new ObjectInputStream(connection3.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(input2);

        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        try {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(connection3.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error creating data input stream ");
        }
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error in creating file input stream");

        }

        int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        try {
            while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                dos.flush();
                System.out.println(fis);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error in loop writing");
        }

        try {

            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error closing fis");
        }
        try {
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("or closing dos");
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        duration = 0;
        audioInputStream = null;

        // define the required attributes for our line,
        // and make sure a compatible line is supported.
        AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        float rate = 44100.0f;
        int channels = 2;
        int frameSize = 4;
        int sampleSize = 16;
        boolean bigEndian = true;

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(encoding, rate, sampleSize, channels, (sampleSize / 8) * channels, rate, bigEndian);

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            shutDown("Line matching " + info + " not supported.");
            return;
        }

        // get and open the target data line for capture.
        try {
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format, line.getBufferSize());
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            shutDown("Unable to open the line: " + ex);
            return;
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            shutDown(ex.toString());
            //JavaSound.showInfoDialog();
            return;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            shutDown(ex.toString());
            return;
        }

        // play back the captured audio data
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int frameSizeInBytes = format.getFrameSize();
        int bufferLengthInFrames = line.getBufferSize() / 8;
        int bufferLengthInBytes = bufferLengthInFrames * frameSizeInBytes;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferLengthInBytes];
        int numBytesRead;

        line.start();

        while (thread != null) {
            if ((numBytesRead = line.read(data, 0, bufferLengthInBytes)) == -1) {
                break;
            }
            out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
        }

        // we reached the end of the stream.
        // stop and close the line.
        line.stop();
        line.close();
        line = null;

        // stop and close the output stream
        try {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // load bytes into the audio input stream for playback
        byte audioBytes[] = out.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioBytes);

        audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(bais, format, audioBytes.length / frameSizeInBytes);

        long milliseconds = (long) ((audioInputStream.getFrameLength() * 1000) / format.getFrameRate());

        duration = milliseconds / 1000.0;

        try {
            AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(voiceOutput));

            sendSound();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }

    public void sendSound() throws IOException {

        connection2 = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 1990);
        System.out.println("send voice");
        OutputStream output2 = new ObjectOutputStream(connection2.getOutputStream());
        output2.flush();
        InputStream input2 = new ObjectInputStream(connection2.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(input2);

        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        try {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(connection2.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error creating data input stream ");
        }
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(voiceOutput);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error in creating file input stream");

        }

        int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        try {
            while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                dos.flush();
                System.out.println(fis);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error in loop writing");
        }

        try {

            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("error closing fis");
        }
        try {
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoRun.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            System.out.println("or closing dos");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
String serverIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

IIRC, this will set the `serverIP` variable to the IP address of the the local host, which is 127.0.0.1.  This is a loopback address and only works on the same device.

You need to tell the client to connect to the IP address of your server as assigned by your router (usually starts with 192.168... on a small network).

If you are on a windows device, you can use the command `ipconfig` in the Command Prompt to find this information, or I think `ifconfig` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luke I've obtained my IP so essentially just to recap.. change serverIP to standard 127.0.0.1 host on the HOST application & create a method to obtain the IP address on the Client-Side? is there any documentation or example code that you know of that would provide achieve this result? thank you

Comment: You don't need to change anything on your server.  You need to tell the client where to connect.  There aren't any methods to "find out" what the servers IP is because it could be anything, the client doesn't know.  This value is normally hard coded or read from a file.

Comment: Alright understood, just put IP address of host in client side where ServerIP is, if I'm not mixing stuff up again.

Comment: this worked just tested it, thanks... would probably be recommended to create a static IP if this is sitting on a PC correct? since the IP normally is dynamic.

Comment: In production, yes definitely.